# dead links after switch to https

Tags: magento-enterprise, redirect, https, htaccess

We switched to full https recently but now we found that the url's in google ( which still point to http ) get redirected to the homepage.

It also is a multi domain installation.

Is there a correct htaccess change to be made so the deeplinks get redirected correctly to there https version?

Comment: If you have `Auto-redirect to Base URL` set to `Yes` in `system->configuration->web->url options` set it to `No`.

Comment: https://www.google.ie/#safe=off&q=apache+redirect+http+to+https